# Como calculo el volumen de un solido generado al girar una curva

Tags: python, numpy, plot

El ejercicio dice: Calcule el volumen
del sólido generado al girar sobre el eje OY la región limitada por las
curvas `x = ((5)**1/2)y**2` , `x = 0`, `y = −1`, `y = 1`.

```py
y = sy.symbols('y')
x= np.linspace(0, 1, 200)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

y1=(x/(5**(1/2)))**(1/2)
ax.plot(x,y1)

y2= -(x/(5**(1/2)))**(1/2)
ax.plot(x,y2)

volumen = sy.N( 2 * sy.pi * ( sy.integrate( x * (( 5** (1/2) ) * y ** 2) , (y,-1,1))))
```

Pero me da error y no se porque, si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería.

Comment: Qué error te da? por favor agrega eso

Comment: Agrega los `import` para no estar adivinando.

Comment: sube el código completo con sus respectivos import para saber que biblioteca estás usando para poder reproducir el error

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Buenas, usando la formula del volumen de revolucion, no te quedaria que el volumen del solido girando sobre OY es 0?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas utilizando la fórmula incorrecta para el volumen de un sólido de revolución. El volumen de un sólido de revolución generado al rotar la región delimitada por las curvas y=f(x), y=g(x) (donde f(x) y g(x) son funciones de x) sobre el eje x es dado por:

```
V = pi * ∫[a,b] (f(x)^2 - g(x)^2) dx
```

En donde a y b son los limites de la region.

Podes probar asi:

```
import sympy as sy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = sy.symbols('y')

def f(y):
    return (5**(1/2)) * y**2

def g(y):
    return 0

a, b = -1, 1

x1 = np.linspace(a, b, 200)
y1 = [f(y) for y in x1]

x2 = np.linspace(a, b, 200)
y2 = [g(y) for y in x2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

ax.plot(x1, y1)
ax.plot(x2, y2)

volumen = sy.N(sy.pi * sy.integrate((f(y)**2 - g(y)**2), (y, a, b)))
print(volumen)
```

Espero haberte ayudado.